# how to graph the appearance (of a word) frequency with gnu plot

Tags: gnuplot

I have a data like this (pasted to the bottom of this question,
it's saved at /tmp/rawdata.txt)
I use bash, and can `brew install gnuplot`  if required

(for the purpose of discussion) Let's say this is 
occurrences of the word "foo" at news.google.com

The stakeholders want to know, is the popularity of "foo"
on the rise or decline.
Popularity is how many times a day/hour/whatever the word "foo"
appears in news.google.com

Can gnu plot help me make a graph I can show the stakeholders?
How can I accomplish this.
I've never used gnu plot, and am on MacOS.

Update:
I tried

```
$ gnuplot

    G N U P L O T
    Version 5.2 patchlevel 4    last modified 2018-06-01

    Copyright (C) 1986-1993, 1998, 2004, 2007-2018
    Thomas Williams, Colin Kelley and many others

    gnuplot home:     http://www.gnuplot.info
    faq, bugs, etc:   type "help FAQ"
    immediate help:   type "help"  (plot window: hit 'h')

Terminal type is now 'qt'
gnuplot> set xdata time
gnuplot> set timefmt "%Y-%m-%y %H:%M:%S"
gnuplot> binwidth = 30
gnuplot> bin(x,width) = width*floor(x/width)
gnuplot> plot "/tmp/2" using (bin(timecolumn(1),binwidth)):(1.0) smooth frequency with boxes
gnuplot>
```

But the result looks weird [image]

```
Wed,  5 Sep 2018 09:47:46 PDT
Wed,  5 Sep 2018 09:30:17 PDT
Wed,  5 Sep 2018 09:09:41 PDT
Wed,  5 Sep 2018 09:07:47 PDT
Wed,  5 Sep 2018 08:19:28 PDT
Wed,  5 Sep 2018 08:12:07 PDT
Wed,  5 Sep 2018 07:27:38 PDT
Wed,  5 Sep 2018 06:49:51 PDT
Wed,  5 Sep 2018 06:45:40 PDT
Wed,  5 Sep 2018 06:38:33 PDT
Wed,  5 Sep 2018 06:32:56 PDT
Wed,  5 Sep 2018 06:09:48 PDT
Wed,  5 Sep 2018 05:50:51 PDT
Wed,  5 Sep 2018 04:44:08 PDT
Wed,  5 Sep 2018 04:03:00 PDT
Wed,  5 Sep 2018 03:22:31 PDT
Wed,  5 Sep 2018 03:04:36 PDT
Wed,  5 Sep 2018 02:39:33 PDT
Wed,  5 Sep 2018 02:11:26 PDT
Wed,  5 Sep 2018 00:59:15 PDT
Wed,  5 Sep 2018 00:34:28 PDT
Tue,  4 Sep 2018 23:04:09 PDT
Tue,  4 Sep 2018 23:02:06 PDT
Tue,  4 Sep 2018 22:34:33 PDT
Tue,  4 Sep 2018 22:21:58 PDT
Tue,  4 Sep 2018 21:35:33 PDT
Tue,  4 Sep 2018 20:33:17 PDT
Tue,  4 Sep 2018 18:57:15 PDT
Tue,  4 Sep 2018 18:53:35 PDT
Tue,  4 Sep 2018 18:49:33 PDT
Tue,  4 Sep 2018 18:47:57 PDT
Tue,  4 Sep 2018 18:15:58 PDT
Tue,  4 Sep 2018 18:13:33 PDT
Tue,  4 Sep 2018 17:59:03 PDT
Tue,  4 Sep 2018 17:03:00 PDT
Tue,  4 Sep 2018 16:21:33 PDT
Tue,  4 Sep 2018 16:04:24 PDT
Tue,  4 Sep 2018 15:36:59 PDT
Tue,  4 Sep 2018 13:42:15 PDT
Tue,  4 Sep 2018 13:07:48 PDT
Tue,  4 Sep 2018 12:49:17 PDT
Tue,  4 Sep 2018 12:45:34 PDT
Tue,  4 Sep 2018 12:17:11 PDT
Tue,  4 Sep 2018 11:57:30 PDT
Tue,  4 Sep 2018 11:36:35 PDT
Tue,  4 Sep 2018 11:03:06 PDT
Tue,  4 Sep 2018 10:59:23 PDT
Tue,  4 Sep 2018 10:42:09 PDT
Tue,  4 Sep 2018 10:22:51 PDT
Tue,  4 Sep 2018 10:14:28 PDT
Tue,  4 Sep 2018 09:41:05 PDT
Tue,  4 Sep 2018 09:18:54 PDT
Tue,  4 Sep 2018 09:18:29 PDT
Tue,  4 Sep 2018 08:55:09 PDT
Tue,  4 Sep 2018 08:52:01 PDT
Tue,  4 Sep 2018 08:10:57 PDT
Tue,  4 Sep 2018 08:09:52 PDT
Tue,  4 Sep 2018 08:04:58 PDT
Tue,  4 Sep 2018 08:00:15 PDT
Tue,  4 Sep 2018 07:19:51 PDT
Tue,  4 Sep 2018 06:50:32 PDT
Tue,  4 Sep 2018 06:21:37 PDT
Tue,  4 Sep 2018 05:00:52 PDT
Tue,  4 Sep 2018 04:50:17 PDT
Tue,  4 Sep 2018 04:39:03 PDT
Tue,  4 Sep 2018 04:25:45 PDT
Tue,  4 Sep 2018 03:56:03 PDT
Tue,  4 Sep 2018 02:31:22 PDT
Tue,  4 Sep 2018 02:29:27 PDT
Tue,  4 Sep 2018 01:09:22 PDT
Tue,  4 Sep 2018 00:55:02 PDT
Tue,  4 Sep 2018 00:28:58 PDT
Mon,  3 Sep 2018 23:49:55 PDT
Mon,  3 Sep 2018 22:49:36 PDT
Mon,  3 Sep 2018 22:44:16 PDT
Mon,  3 Sep 2018 21:47:34 PDT
Mon,  3 Sep 2018 20:48:45 PDT
Mon,  3 Sep 2018 20:31:17 PDT
Mon,  3 Sep 2018 16:44:53 PDT
Mon,  3 Sep 2018 16:21:52 PDT
Sat,  1 Sep 2018 13:49:27 PDT
Sat,  1 Sep 2018 10:54:51 PDT
Sat,  1 Sep 2018 10:52:27 PDT
Sat,  1 Sep 2018 10:47:14 PDT
Sat,  1 Sep 2018 10:47:13 PDT
Sat,  1 Sep 2018 08:16:42 PDT
Sat,  1 Sep 2018 04:49:46 PDT
Sat,  1 Sep 2018 00:05:18 PDT
Fri, 31 Aug 2018 23:20:27 PDT
Fri, 31 Aug 2018 22:51:19 PDT
Fri, 31 Aug 2018 22:38:16 PDT
Fri, 31 Aug 2018 20:59:32 PDT
Fri, 31 Aug 2018 20:38:13 PDT
Fri, 31 Aug 2018 17:03:22 PDT
Fri, 31 Aug 2018 14:56:15 PDT
Fri, 31 Aug 2018 13:18:54 PDT
Fri, 31 Aug 2018 11:49:40 PDT
Fri, 31 Aug 2018 11:45:02 PDT
Fri, 31 Aug 2018 10:23:57 PDT
Fri, 31 Aug 2018 09:12:14 PDT
Fri, 31 Aug 2018 09:03:38 PDT
Fri, 31 Aug 2018 08:13:42 PDT
Fri, 31 Aug 2018 07:42:29 PDT
Fri, 31 Aug 2018 06:40:57 PDT
Fri, 31 Aug 2018 06:25:16 PDT
Fri, 31 Aug 2018 05:47:39 PDT
Fri, 31 Aug 2018 03:39:27 PDT
Fri, 31 Aug 2018 03:26:34 PDT
Fri, 31 Aug 2018 03:12:35 PDT
Fri, 31 Aug 2018 00:45:32 PDT
Fri, 31 Aug 2018 00:38:49 PDT
Thu, 30 Aug 2018 23:48:37 PDT
Thu, 30 Aug 2018 23:27:38 PDT
Thu, 30 Aug 2018 23:24:07 PDT
Thu, 30 Aug 2018 21:56:42 PDT
Thu, 30 Aug 2018 20:27:32 PDT
Thu, 30 Aug 2018 20:21:53 PDT
Thu, 30 Aug 2018 19:53:20 PDT
Thu, 30 Aug 2018 18:58:40 PDT
Thu, 30 Aug 2018 18:44:20 PDT
Thu, 30 Aug 2018 18:14:19 PDT
Thu, 30 Aug 2018 17:50:41 PDT
Thu, 30 Aug 2018 17:29:37 PDT
Thu, 30 Aug 2018 17:10:26 PDT
Thu, 30 Aug 2018 17:02:23 PDT
Thu, 30 Aug 2018 16:46:49 PDT
Thu, 30 Aug 2018 16:30:07 PDT
Thu, 30 Aug 2018 16:25:13 PDT
Thu, 30 Aug 2018 16:22:42 PDT
Thu, 30 Aug 2018 16:01:53 PDT
Thu, 30 Aug 2018 14:41:46 PDT
Thu, 30 Aug 2018 14:09:48 PDT
Thu, 30 Aug 2018 13:25:30 PDT
Thu, 30 Aug 2018 13:23:06 PDT
Thu, 30 Aug 2018 12:57:17 PDT
Thu, 30 Aug 2018 12:07:02 PDT
Thu, 30 Aug 2018 12:03:10 PDT
Thu, 30 Aug 2018 11:27:50 PDT
Thu, 30 Aug 2018 11:22:46 PDT
Thu, 30 Aug 2018 09:59:22 PDT
Thu, 30 Aug 2018 09:30:05 PDT
Thu, 30 Aug 2018 09:23:56 PDT
Thu, 30 Aug 2018 08:53:32 PDT
Thu, 30 Aug 2018 08:05:28 PDT
Thu, 30 Aug 2018 07:59:50 PDT
Thu, 30 Aug 2018 07:17:22 PDT
Thu, 30 Aug 2018 06:35:26 PDT
Thu, 30 Aug 2018 06:34:22 PDT
Thu, 30 Aug 2018 06:20:43 PDT
Thu, 30 Aug 2018 05:22:11 PDT
Thu, 30 Aug 2018 05:16:17 PDT
Thu, 30 Aug 2018 04:51:15 PDT
Thu, 30 Aug 2018 04:30:46 PDT
Thu, 30 Aug 2018 02:39:36 PDT
Thu, 30 Aug 2018 02:10:01 PDT
Thu, 30 Aug 2018 01:50:40 PDT
Wed, 29 Aug 2018 23:53:40 PDT
Wed, 29 Aug 2018 23:12:12 PDT
Wed, 29 Aug 2018 22:16:40 PDT
Wed, 29 Aug 2018 22:04:19 PDT
Wed, 29 Aug 2018 21:51:07 PDT
Wed, 29 Aug 2018 21:47:45 PDT
Wed, 29 Aug 2018 21:31:38 PDT
Wed, 29 Aug 2018 20:47:19 PDT
Wed, 29 Aug 2018 14:38:10 PDT
Wed, 29 Aug 2018 12:26:43 PDT
Wed, 29 Aug 2018 12:10:36 PDT
Wed, 29 Aug 2018 11:58:56 PDT
Wed, 29 Aug 2018 11:56:17 PDT
Wed, 29 Aug 2018 11:29:13 PDT
Wed, 29 Aug 2018 11:25:39 PDT
Wed, 29 Aug 2018 10:44:23 PDT
Wed, 29 Aug 2018 10:43:59 PDT
Wed, 29 Aug 2018 09:58:30 PDT
Wed, 29 Aug 2018 09:52:43 PDT
Wed, 29 Aug 2018 09:46:49 PDT
Wed, 29 Aug 2018 09:30:05 PDT
Wed, 29 Aug 2018 09:20:14 PDT
Wed, 29 Aug 2018 08:22:24 PDT
Wed, 29 Aug 2018 07:44:06 PDT
Wed, 29 Aug 2018 07:18:57 PDT
Wed, 29 Aug 2018 06:08:37 PDT
Tue, 28 Aug 2018 16:39:09 PDT
Tue, 28 Aug 2018 15:43:00 PDT
Tue, 28 Aug 2018 15:16:11 PDT
Tue, 28 Aug 2018 14:22:27 PDT
Tue, 28 Aug 2018 14:16:54 PDT
Tue, 28 Aug 2018 13:57:13 PDT
Tue, 28 Aug 2018 12:36:36 PDT
Tue, 28 Aug 2018 11:47:37 PDT
Tue, 28 Aug 2018 11:46:50 PDT
Tue, 28 Aug 2018 11:12:09 PDT
Tue, 28 Aug 2018 10:28:57 PDT
Tue, 28 Aug 2018 09:58:47 PDT
Tue, 28 Aug 2018 09:15:46 PDT
Tue, 28 Aug 2018 08:51:55 PDT
Tue, 28 Aug 2018 08:13:18 PDT
Tue, 28 Aug 2018 06:33:04 PDT
Tue, 28 Aug 2018 06:33:04 PDT
Mon, 27 Aug 2018 21:56:52 PDT
Mon, 27 Aug 2018 18:34:38 PDT
Mon, 27 Aug 2018 18:20:01 PDT
Mon, 27 Aug 2018 15:25:54 PDT
Mon, 27 Aug 2018 15:23:26 PDT
Mon, 27 Aug 2018 11:00:02 PDT
Mon, 27 Aug 2018 10:26:37 PDT
Mon, 27 Aug 2018 10:26:10 PDT
Mon, 27 Aug 2018 10:21:21 PDT
Mon, 27 Aug 2018 10:14:29 PDT
Mon, 27 Aug 2018 09:05:18 PDT
Mon, 27 Aug 2018 05:57:49 PDT
Mon, 27 Aug 2018 05:48:05 PDT
Mon, 27 Aug 2018 05:46:42 PDT
Mon, 27 Aug 2018 04:35:11 PDT
Mon, 27 Aug 2018 03:51:19 PDT
Mon, 27 Aug 2018 03:23:45 PDT
Mon, 27 Aug 2018 01:21:36 PDT
Mon, 27 Aug 2018 00:07:24 PDT
Sun, 26 Aug 2018 23:27:56 PDT
Sun, 26 Aug 2018 21:10:00 PDT
Sun, 26 Aug 2018 19:59:12 PDT
Sun, 26 Aug 2018 18:58:47 PDT
Sun, 26 Aug 2018 18:15:06 PDT
Sun, 26 Aug 2018 14:30:15 PDT
Sun, 26 Aug 2018 10:29:38 PDT
Sun, 26 Aug 2018 10:09:57 PDT
Sun, 26 Aug 2018 08:40:39 PDT
Sun, 26 Aug 2018 08:24:18 PDT
Sun, 26 Aug 2018 08:14:35 PDT
Sun, 26 Aug 2018 05:26:40 PDT
Sun, 26 Aug 2018 04:05:25 PDT
Sun, 26 Aug 2018 03:49:18 PDT
Sun, 26 Aug 2018 00:41:45 PDT
Sat, 25 Aug 2018 23:57:24 PDT
Sat, 25 Aug 2018 22:46:44 PDT
Fri, 24 Aug 2018 15:45:24 PDT
Fri, 24 Aug 2018 15:27:31 PDT
Fri, 24 Aug 2018 13:07:05 PDT
Fri, 24 Aug 2018 11:44:20 PDT
Fri, 24 Aug 2018 11:35:18 PDT
Fri, 24 Aug 2018 10:30:45 PDT
Fri, 24 Aug 2018 10:20:52 PDT
Fri, 24 Aug 2018 10:14:02 PDT
Fri, 24 Aug 2018 09:26:20 PDT
Fri, 24 Aug 2018 07:59:21 PDT
Fri, 24 Aug 2018 06:32:13 PDT
Fri, 24 Aug 2018 02:48:54 PDT
Fri, 24 Aug 2018 02:37:29 PDT
Fri, 24 Aug 2018 00:54:14 PDT
Fri, 24 Aug 2018 00:00:22 PDT
Thu, 23 Aug 2018 20:55:39 PDT
Thu, 23 Aug 2018 20:27:20 PDT
Thu, 23 Aug 2018 14:07:57 PDT
Thu, 23 Aug 2018 13:38:53 PDT
Thu, 23 Aug 2018 13:24:31 PDT
Thu, 23 Aug 2018 12:31:13 PDT
Thu, 23 Aug 2018 12:29:40 PDT
Thu, 23 Aug 2018 12:25:11 PDT
Thu, 23 Aug 2018 12:03:32 PDT
Thu, 23 Aug 2018 11:20:27 PDT
Thu, 23 Aug 2018 10:07:59 PDT
Thu, 23 Aug 2018 09:54:38 PDT
Thu, 23 Aug 2018 09:49:41 PDT
Thu, 23 Aug 2018 09:47:23 PDT
Thu, 23 Aug 2018 09:34:49 PDT
Thu, 23 Aug 2018 09:18:46 PDT
Thu, 23 Aug 2018 07:38:43 PDT
Thu, 23 Aug 2018 07:15:58 PDT
Thu, 23 Aug 2018 02:38:00 PDT
Thu, 23 Aug 2018 02:28:23 PDT
Thu, 23 Aug 2018 02:04:10 PDT
Thu, 23 Aug 2018 01:59:57 PDT
Thu, 23 Aug 2018 00:30:17 PDT
Wed, 22 Aug 2018 22:52:09 PDT
Wed, 22 Aug 2018 21:21:19 PDT
Wed, 22 Aug 2018 19:22:01 PDT
Wed, 22 Aug 2018 18:58:15 PDT
Wed, 22 Aug 2018 18:13:49 PDT
Wed, 22 Aug 2018 18:06:13 PDT
Wed, 22 Aug 2018 17:49:29 PDT
Wed, 22 Aug 2018 16:56:18 PDT
Wed, 22 Aug 2018 16:55:09 PDT
Wed, 22 Aug 2018 16:10:14 PDT
Wed, 22 Aug 2018 15:36:48 PDT
Wed, 22 Aug 2018 14:07:47 PDT
Wed, 22 Aug 2018 13:57:27 PDT
Wed, 22 Aug 2018 12:19:36 PDT
Wed, 22 Aug 2018 12:18:02 PDT
Wed, 22 Aug 2018 09:02:37 PDT
Wed, 22 Aug 2018 08:52:57 PDT
Wed, 22 Aug 2018 08:32:45 PDT
Wed, 22 Aug 2018 08:31:25 PDT
Wed, 22 Aug 2018 08:09:37 PDT
Wed, 22 Aug 2018 07:37:38 PDT
Wed, 22 Aug 2018 07:30:22 PDT
Wed, 22 Aug 2018 06:55:27 PDT
Wed, 22 Aug 2018 06:45:53 PDT
Wed, 22 Aug 2018 06:37:22 PDT
Wed, 22 Aug 2018 04:26:20 PDT
Wed, 22 Aug 2018 03:52:11 PDT
Wed, 22 Aug 2018 03:12:57 PDT
Wed, 22 Aug 2018 03:10:24 PDT
Wed, 22 Aug 2018 02:52:19 PDT
Wed, 22 Aug 2018 02:15:52 PDT
Wed, 22 Aug 2018 02:15:11 PDT
Wed, 22 Aug 2018 01:55:32 PDT
Wed, 22 Aug 2018 01:50:18 PDT
Wed, 22 Aug 2018 01:20:15 PDT
Wed, 22 Aug 2018 00:52:49 PDT
Tue, 21 Aug 2018 23:26:11 PDT
Tue, 21 Aug 2018 22:14:54 PDT
Tue, 21 Aug 2018 21:51:37 PDT
Tue, 21 Aug 2018 21:15:16 PDT
Tue, 21 Aug 2018 20:05:31 PDT
Tue, 21 Aug 2018 18:46:46 PDT
Tue, 21 Aug 2018 17:37:22 PDT
Tue, 21 Aug 2018 16:12:01 PDT
Tue, 21 Aug 2018 15:50:42 PDT
Tue, 21 Aug 2018 15:19:00 PDT
Tue, 21 Aug 2018 14:09:43 PDT
Tue, 21 Aug 2018 13:00:18 PDT
Tue, 21 Aug 2018 11:50:50 PDT
Tue, 21 Aug 2018 11:25:44 PDT
Tue, 21 Aug 2018 08:45:54 PDT
Tue, 21 Aug 2018 07:59:23 PDT
Tue, 21 Aug 2018 03:20:16 PDT
Tue, 21 Aug 2018 03:12:49 PDT
Tue, 21 Aug 2018 02:09:38 PDT
Tue, 21 Aug 2018 01:52:04 PDT
Mon, 20 Aug 2018 20:12:16 PDT
Mon, 20 Aug 2018 20:10:18 PDT
Mon, 20 Aug 2018 18:08:40 PDT
Mon, 20 Aug 2018 18:03:19 PDT
Mon, 20 Aug 2018 17:54:10 PDT
Mon, 20 Aug 2018 15:03:17 PDT
Mon, 20 Aug 2018 13:20:50 PDT
Mon, 20 Aug 2018 10:51:05 PDT
Mon, 20 Aug 2018 10:11:13 PDT
Mon, 20 Aug 2018 10:08:49 PDT
Mon, 20 Aug 2018 09:37:15 PDT
Mon, 20 Aug 2018 09:08:45 PDT
Mon, 20 Aug 2018 09:07:46 PDT
Mon, 20 Aug 2018 08:44:39 PDT
Mon, 20 Aug 2018 07:53:31 PDT
Mon, 20 Aug 2018 05:59:34 PDT
Mon, 20 Aug 2018 05:50:34 PDT
Mon, 20 Aug 2018 05:49:22 PDT
Mon, 20 Aug 2018 05:20:11 PDT
Mon, 20 Aug 2018 05:19:24 PDT
Mon, 20 Aug 2018 04:51:45 PDT
Mon, 20 Aug 2018 03:11:53 PDT
Mon, 20 Aug 2018 02:44:01 PDT
Sun, 19 Aug 2018 21:41:43 PDT
Sun, 19 Aug 2018 20:35:47 PDT
Sun, 19 Aug 2018 19:57:58 PDT
Sun, 19 Aug 2018 19:21:13 PDT
Sun, 19 Aug 2018 17:41:16 PDT
Sun, 19 Aug 2018 17:37:13 PDT
Sun, 19 Aug 2018 17:32:05 PDT
Sun, 19 Aug 2018 13:57:06 PDT
Sun, 19 Aug 2018 10:54:45 PDT
Sun, 19 Aug 2018 07:57:06 PDT
Sun, 19 Aug 2018 02:15:58 PDT
Sun, 19 Aug 2018 01:37:54 PDT
Sat, 18 Aug 2018 23:12:03 PDT
Sat, 18 Aug 2018 17:38:58 PDT
Sat, 18 Aug 2018 16:53:50 PDT
Sat, 18 Aug 2018 13:49:09 PDT
Sat, 18 Aug 2018 13:34:25 PDT
Sat, 18 Aug 2018 12:09:01 PDT
Sat, 18 Aug 2018 10:24:39 PDT
Sat, 18 Aug 2018 08:10:34 PDT
Sat, 18 Aug 2018 06:30:45 PDT
Sat, 18 Aug 2018 06:25:08 PDT
Sat, 18 Aug 2018 06:22:09 PDT
Sat, 18 Aug 2018 03:11:52 PDT
Fri, 17 Aug 2018 20:32:56 PDT
Fri, 17 Aug 2018 19:32:30 PDT
Fri, 17 Aug 2018 15:27:03 PDT
Fri, 17 Aug 2018 15:16:01 PDT
Fri, 17 Aug 2018 14:58:38 PDT
Fri, 17 Aug 2018 14:36:33 PDT
Fri, 17 Aug 2018 13:52:41 PDT
Fri, 17 Aug 2018 13:47:42 PDT
Fri, 17 Aug 2018 13:45:43 PDT
Fri, 17 Aug 2018 12:29:36 PDT
Fri, 17 Aug 2018 12:07:48 PDT
Fri, 17 Aug 2018 12:03:56 PDT
Fri, 17 Aug 2018 11:59:45 PDT
Fri, 17 Aug 2018 11:16:58 PDT
Fri, 17 Aug 2018 10:16:59 PDT
Fri, 17 Aug 2018 09:11:51 PDT
Fri, 17 Aug 2018 08:06:00 PDT
Fri, 17 Aug 2018 07:30:17 PDT
Fri, 17 Aug 2018 06:56:35 PDT
Fri, 17 Aug 2018 06:23:37 PDT
Fri, 17 Aug 2018 06:17:32 PDT
Fri, 17 Aug 2018 06:08:50 PDT
Fri, 17 Aug 2018 04:42:16 PDT
Fri, 17 Aug 2018 04:03:28 PDT
Fri, 17 Aug 2018 03:27:18 PDT
Fri, 17 Aug 2018 01:36:42 PDT
Fri, 17 Aug 2018 01:34:20 PDT
Fri, 17 Aug 2018 01:02:06 PDT
Thu, 16 Aug 2018 22:45:19 PDT
Thu, 16 Aug 2018 22:42:45 PDT
Thu, 16 Aug 2018 21:38:48 PDT
Thu, 16 Aug 2018 21:04:19 PDT
Thu, 16 Aug 2018 20:53:16 PDT
Thu, 16 Aug 2018 18:03:02 PDT
Thu, 16 Aug 2018 18:00:23 PDT
Thu, 16 Aug 2018 17:57:20 PDT
Thu, 16 Aug 2018 15:29:39 PDT
Thu, 16 Aug 2018 15:22:13 PDT
Thu, 16 Aug 2018 14:26:13 PDT
Thu, 16 Aug 2018 13:54:54 PDT
Thu, 16 Aug 2018 13:17:44 PDT
Thu, 16 Aug 2018 13:12:59 PDT
Thu, 16 Aug 2018 12:46:49 PDT
Thu, 16 Aug 2018 11:53:08 PDT
Thu, 16 Aug 2018 11:17:37 PDT
Thu, 16 Aug 2018 11:16:29 PDT
Thu, 16 Aug 2018 11:12:53 PDT
Thu, 16 Aug 2018 09:42:30 PDT
Thu, 16 Aug 2018 09:12:00 PDT
Thu, 16 Aug 2018 07:41:00 PDT
Thu, 16 Aug 2018 07:13:12 PDT
Thu, 16 Aug 2018 07:11:45 PDT
Thu, 16 Aug 2018 07:10:03 PDT
Thu, 16 Aug 2018 06:32:29 PDT
Thu, 16 Aug 2018 06:17:57 PDT
Thu, 16 Aug 2018 06:11:02 PDT
Thu, 16 Aug 2018 05:38:19 PDT
Thu, 16 Aug 2018 05:14:10 PDT
Thu, 16 Aug 2018 04:38:06 PDT
Thu, 16 Aug 2018 02:30:31 PDT
Thu, 16 Aug 2018 02:05:07 PDT
Thu, 16 Aug 2018 01:34:28 PDT
Thu, 16 Aug 2018 01:34:07 PDT
Thu, 16 Aug 2018 00:03:59 PDT
Wed, 15 Aug 2018 23:20:12 PDT
Wed, 15 Aug 2018 23:10:45 PDT
Wed, 15 Aug 2018 21:45:32 PDT
Wed, 15 Aug 2018 21:00:18 PDT
Wed, 15 Aug 2018 19:48:18 PDT
Wed, 15 Aug 2018 18:11:41 PDT
Wed, 15 Aug 2018 17:50:05 PDT
Wed, 15 Aug 2018 14:56:10 PDT
Wed, 15 Aug 2018 14:18:02 PDT
Wed, 15 Aug 2018 13:49:58 PDT
Wed, 15 Aug 2018 13:40:13 PDT
Wed, 15 Aug 2018 13:20:08 PDT
Wed, 15 Aug 2018 13:02:06 PDT
Wed, 15 Aug 2018 12:37:03 PDT
Wed, 15 Aug 2018 12:04:03 PDT
Wed, 15 Aug 2018 11:42:23 PDT
Wed, 15 Aug 2018 09:05:06 PDT
Wed, 15 Aug 2018 08:51:05 PDT
Wed, 15 Aug 2018 08:40:47 PDT
Wed, 15 Aug 2018 07:54:31 PDT
Wed, 15 Aug 2018 07:43:04 PDT
Wed, 15 Aug 2018 06:34:20 PDT
Wed, 15 Aug 2018 06:22:45 PDT
Wed, 15 Aug 2018 06:17:00 PDT
Wed, 15 Aug 2018 06:01:51 PDT
Wed, 15 Aug 2018 03:32:50 PDT
Wed, 15 Aug 2018 03:31:07 PDT
Wed, 15 Aug 2018 03:24:21 PDT
Wed, 15 Aug 2018 03:17:28 PDT
Wed, 15 Aug 2018 02:09:15 PDT
Wed, 15 Aug 2018 00:43:52 PDT
Tue, 14 Aug 2018 23:17:47 PDT
Tue, 14 Aug 2018 23:08:37 PDT
Tue, 14 Aug 2018 12:32:44 PDT
Sun, 12 Aug 2018 23:00:55 PDT
Sat, 11 Aug 2018 09:26:35 PDT
Fri, 10 Aug 2018 08:31:12 PDT
Fri, 10 Aug 2018 06:55:08 PDT
Fri, 10 Aug 2018 05:41:09 PDT
Fri, 10 Aug 2018 03:55:37 PDT
Fri, 10 Aug 2018 03:13:18 PDT
Fri, 10 Aug 2018 03:10:21 PDT
Fri, 10 Aug 2018 02:38:34 PDT
Fri, 10 Aug 2018 01:48:24 PDT
Fri, 10 Aug 2018 01:10:37 PDT
Fri, 10 Aug 2018 00:51:54 PDT
Thu,  9 Aug 2018 23:59:24 PDT
Thu,  9 Aug 2018 23:11:59 PDT
Thu,  9 Aug 2018 21:59:49 PDT
Thu,  9 Aug 2018 20:41:05 PDT
Thu,  9 Aug 2018 20:38:34 PDT
Thu,  9 Aug 2018 19:57:17 PDT
Thu,  9 Aug 2018 19:21:58 PDT
Thu,  9 Aug 2018 19:05:35 PDT
Thu,  9 Aug 2018 18:38:37 PDT
Thu,  9 Aug 2018 18:35:44 PDT
Thu,  9 Aug 2018 16:14:02 PDT
Thu,  9 Aug 2018 16:00:21 PDT
Thu,  9 Aug 2018 14:20:03 PDT
Thu,  9 Aug 2018 13:39:10 PDT
Thu,  9 Aug 2018 13:29:27 PDT
Thu,  9 Aug 2018 12:18:28 PDT
Thu,  9 Aug 2018 10:08:32 PDT
Thu,  9 Aug 2018 09:55:38 PDT
Thu,  9 Aug 2018 08:11:44 PDT
Thu,  9 Aug 2018 07:25:45 PDT
Thu,  9 Aug 2018 00:35:43 PDT
Thu,  9 Aug 2018 00:32:53 PDT
Wed,  8 Aug 2018 23:17:58 PDT
Wed,  8 Aug 2018 23:01:10 PDT
Wed,  8 Aug 2018 21:23:56 PDT
Wed,  8 Aug 2018 20:56:14 PDT
Wed,  8 Aug 2018 19:37:15 PDT
Wed,  8 Aug 2018 19:26:24 PDT
Wed,  8 Aug 2018 19:19:09 PDT
Wed,  8 Aug 2018 16:16:35 PDT
Wed,  8 Aug 2018 16:14:46 PDT
Wed,  8 Aug 2018 15:40:28 PDT
Wed,  8 Aug 2018 15:39:34 PDT
Wed,  8 Aug 2018 15:28:19 PDT
Wed,  8 Aug 2018 15:03:25 PDT
Wed,  8 Aug 2018 13:17:37 PDT
Wed,  8 Aug 2018 13:01:06 PDT
Wed,  8 Aug 2018 12:43:56 PDT
Wed,  8 Aug 2018 12:43:46 PDT
Wed,  8 Aug 2018 08:57:55 PDT
Wed,  8 Aug 2018 06:36:07 PDT
Wed,  8 Aug 2018 06:01:03 PDT
Wed,  8 Aug 2018 05:47:36 PDT
Wed,  8 Aug 2018 05:38:38 PDT
Wed,  8 Aug 2018 04:45:12 PDT
Wed,  8 Aug 2018 01:55:56 PDT
Tue,  7 Aug 2018 22:11:25 PDT
Tue,  7 Aug 2018 22:08:23 PDT
Tue,  7 Aug 2018 21:50:20 PDT
Tue,  7 Aug 2018 20:34:12 PDT
Tue,  7 Aug 2018 18:47:59 PDT
Tue,  7 Aug 2018 17:49:06 PDT
Tue,  7 Aug 2018 17:34:14 PDT
Tue,  7 Aug 2018 16:04:08 PDT
Tue,  7 Aug 2018 15:32:16 PDT
Tue,  7 Aug 2018 12:29:49 PDT
Tue,  7 Aug 2018 11:26:18 PDT
Tue,  7 Aug 2018 11:18:05 PDT
Tue,  7 Aug 2018 10:29:36 PDT
Tue,  7 Aug 2018 10:11:04 PDT
Tue,  7 Aug 2018 09:23:43 PDT
Tue,  7 Aug 2018 09:09:22 PDT
Tue,  7 Aug 2018 09:00:20 PDT
Tue,  7 Aug 2018 08:38:30 PDT
Tue,  7 Aug 2018 08:34:56 PDT
Tue,  7 Aug 2018 08:15:33 PDT
Tue,  7 Aug 2018 08:15:08 PDT
Tue,  7 Aug 2018 06:49:31 PDT
Tue,  7 Aug 2018 05:36:42 PDT
Tue,  7 Aug 2018 00:34:40 PDT
Tue,  7 Aug 2018 00:04:50 PDT
Mon,  6 Aug 2018 23:30:00 PDT
Mon,  6 Aug 2018 23:01:02 PDT
Mon,  6 Aug 2018 22:53:53 PDT
Mon,  6 Aug 2018 19:20:36 PDT
Mon,  6 Aug 2018 15:49:54 PDT
Mon,  6 Aug 2018 15:21:23 PDT
Mon,  6 Aug 2018 14:43:58 PDT
Mon,  6 Aug 2018 14:10:50 PDT
Mon,  6 Aug 2018 14:06:23 PDT
Mon,  6 Aug 2018 13:44:40 PDT
Mon,  6 Aug 2018 12:06:05 PDT
Mon,  6 Aug 2018 12:03:35 PDT
Mon,  6 Aug 2018 11:48:06 PDT
Mon,  6 Aug 2018 11:36:52 PDT
Mon,  6 Aug 2018 10:46:09 PDT
Mon,  6 Aug 2018 10:37:41 PDT
Mon,  6 Aug 2018 09:59:46 PDT
Mon,  6 Aug 2018 09:19:55 PDT
Mon,  6 Aug 2018 09:15:35 PDT
Mon,  6 Aug 2018 08:53:24 PDT
Mon,  6 Aug 2018 08:23:11 PDT
Mon,  6 Aug 2018 08:07:36 PDT
Mon,  6 Aug 2018 06:13:20 PDT
Mon,  6 Aug 2018 05:59:58 PDT
Mon,  6 Aug 2018 05:48:10 PDT
Mon,  6 Aug 2018 03:42:38 PDT
Mon,  6 Aug 2018 03:19:45 PDT
Mon,  6 Aug 2018 02:29:01 PDT
Mon,  6 Aug 2018 01:45:47 PDT
Mon,  6 Aug 2018 01:24:30 PDT
Sun,  5 Aug 2018 23:42:59 PDT
Sun,  5 Aug 2018 22:08:52 PDT
Sun,  5 Aug 2018 21:34:08 PDT
Sun,  5 Aug 2018 21:01:15 PDT
Sun,  5 Aug 2018 20:50:56 PDT
Sun,  5 Aug 2018 20:02:12 PDT
Sun,  5 Aug 2018 19:47:43 PDT
Sun,  5 Aug 2018 18:55:40 PDT
Sun,  5 Aug 2018 18:10:45 PDT
Sun,  5 Aug 2018 17:50:18 PDT
Sun,  5 Aug 2018 15:36:13 PDT
Sun,  5 Aug 2018 13:53:12 PDT
Sun,  5 Aug 2018 13:01:17 PDT
Sun,  5 Aug 2018 12:45:27 PDT
Sun,  5 Aug 2018 06:48:53 PDT
Sun,  5 Aug 2018 00:40:53 PDT
Sat,  4 Aug 2018 18:29:20 PDT
Sat,  4 Aug 2018 15:38:50 PDT
Sat,  4 Aug 2018 14:47:44 PDT
Sat,  4 Aug 2018 14:38:56 PDT
Sat,  4 Aug 2018 14:36:53 PDT
Sat,  4 Aug 2018 10:01:32 PDT
Sat,  4 Aug 2018 04:52:30 PDT
Fri,  3 Aug 2018 20:57:42 PDT
Fri,  3 Aug 2018 20:15:04 PDT
Fri,  3 Aug 2018 17:32:50 PDT
Fri,  3 Aug 2018 16:24:22 PDT
Fri,  3 Aug 2018 15:48:45 PDT
Fri,  3 Aug 2018 15:40:52 PDT
Fri,  3 Aug 2018 14:27:36 PDT
Fri,  3 Aug 2018 13:59:15 PDT
Fri,  3 Aug 2018 13:40:21 PDT
Fri,  3 Aug 2018 12:33:09 PDT
Fri,  3 Aug 2018 09:52:59 PDT
Fri,  3 Aug 2018 08:36:43 PDT
Fri,  3 Aug 2018 07:59:26 PDT
Fri,  3 Aug 2018 06:53:59 PDT
Fri,  3 Aug 2018 06:44:13 PDT
Fri,  3 Aug 2018 05:58:03 PDT
Fri,  3 Aug 2018 05:30:20 PDT
Fri,  3 Aug 2018 03:24:30 PDT
Thu,  2 Aug 2018 23:53:17 PDT
Thu,  2 Aug 2018 22:48:59 PDT
Thu,  2 Aug 2018 21:59:06 PDT
Thu,  2 Aug 2018 21:06:01 PDT
Thu,  2 Aug 2018 20:37:45 PDT
Thu,  2 Aug 2018 18:58:55 PDT
Thu,  2 Aug 2018 16:06:43 PDT
Thu,  2 Aug 2018 14:05:31 PDT
Thu,  2 Aug 2018 13:47:08 PDT
Thu,  2 Aug 2018 13:25:09 PDT
Thu,  2 Aug 2018 12:45:49 PDT
Thu,  2 Aug 2018 11:24:55 PDT
Thu,  2 Aug 2018 09:44:01 PDT
Thu,  2 Aug 2018 09:04:58 PDT
Thu,  2 Aug 2018 08:55:37 PDT
Thu,  2 Aug 2018 08:19:09 PDT
Thu,  2 Aug 2018 06:41:45 PDT
Thu,  2 Aug 2018 06:16:22 PDT
Thu,  2 Aug 2018 03:45:36 PDT
Thu,  2 Aug 2018 03:35:34 PDT
Thu,  2 Aug 2018 01:32:07 PDT
Wed,  1 Aug 2018 23:25:47 PDT
Wed,  1 Aug 2018 23:19:42 PDT
Wed,  1 Aug 2018 23:00:41 PDT
Wed,  1 Aug 2018 21:22:18 PDT
Wed,  1 Aug 2018 21:07:04 PDT
Wed,  1 Aug 2018 20:16:48 PDT
Wed,  1 Aug 2018 17:42:46 PDT
Wed,  1 Aug 2018 15:23:33 PDT
Wed,  1 Aug 2018 13:23:37 PDT
Wed,  1 Aug 2018 13:08:30 PDT
Wed,  1 Aug 2018 11:05:01 PDT
Wed,  1 Aug 2018 10:18:25 PDT
Wed,  1 Aug 2018 09:33:20 PDT
Wed,  1 Aug 2018 09:00:56 PDT
Wed,  1 Aug 2018 08:09:49 PDT
Wed,  1 Aug 2018 08:00:45 PDT
Wed,  1 Aug 2018 05:07:16 PDT
Wed,  1 Aug 2018 04:30:54 PDT
Wed,  1 Aug 2018 03:37:09 PDT
Wed,  1 Aug 2018 01:41:58 PDT
Wed,  1 Aug 2018 01:26:59 PDT
Wed,  1 Aug 2018 00:31:23 PDT
Wed,  1 Aug 2018 00:05:00 PDT
Tue, 31 Jul 2018 23:18:06 PDT
Tue, 31 Jul 2018 22:40:23 PDT
Tue, 31 Jul 2018 20:36:25 PDT
Tue, 31 Jul 2018 19:17:09 PDT
Tue, 31 Jul 2018 18:06:54 PDT
Tue, 31 Jul 2018 16:46:36 PDT
Tue, 31 Jul 2018 15:49:38 PDT
Tue, 31 Jul 2018 15:35:47 PDT
Tue, 31 Jul 2018 14:13:46 PDT
Tue, 31 Jul 2018 13:33:57 PDT
Tue, 31 Jul 2018 13:01:09 PDT
Tue, 31 Jul 2018 12:58:59 PDT
Tue, 31 Jul 2018 12:04:17 PDT
Tue, 31 Jul 2018 12:00:51 PDT
Tue, 31 Jul 2018 10:06:36 PDT
Tue, 31 Jul 2018 09:29:31 PDT
Tue, 31 Jul 2018 09:06:59 PDT
Tue, 31 Jul 2018 08:50:06 PDT
Tue, 31 Jul 2018 08:13:45 PDT
Tue, 31 Jul 2018 07:38:49 PDT
Tue, 31 Jul 2018 06:35:11 PDT
Tue, 31 Jul 2018 03:30:35 PDT
Tue, 31 Jul 2018 03:11:18 PDT
Tue, 31 Jul 2018 02:19:54 PDT
Mon, 30 Jul 2018 21:03:15 PDT
Mon, 30 Jul 2018 16:45:34 PDT
Mon, 30 Jul 2018 16:32:48 PDT
Mon, 30 Jul 2018 16:13:26 PDT
Mon, 30 Jul 2018 14:00:02 PDT
Mon, 30 Jul 2018 13:35:19 PDT
Mon, 30 Jul 2018 13:00:29 PDT
Mon, 30 Jul 2018 12:56:38 PDT
Mon, 30 Jul 2018 12:21:15 PDT
Mon, 30 Jul 2018 12:04:48 PDT
Mon, 30 Jul 2018 11:05:26 PDT
Mon, 30 Jul 2018 10:49:25 PDT
Mon, 30 Jul 2018 09:55:06 PDT
Mon, 30 Jul 2018 09:18:49 PDT
Mon, 30 Jul 2018 08:25:59 PDT
Mon, 30 Jul 2018 08:04:06 PDT
Mon, 30 Jul 2018 07:51:47 PDT
Mon, 30 Jul 2018 07:28:01 PDT
Mon, 30 Jul 2018 07:05:54 PDT
Mon, 30 Jul 2018 07:01:18 PDT
Mon, 30 Jul 2018 06:53:46 PDT
Mon, 30 Jul 2018 06:48:06 PDT
Mon, 30 Jul 2018 06:10:03 PDT
Mon, 30 Jul 2018 01:52:04 PDT
Sun, 29 Jul 2018 22:09:37 PDT
Sun, 29 Jul 2018 16:14:41 PDT
Sun, 29 Jul 2018 15:35:51 PDT
Sun, 29 Jul 2018 15:18:35 PDT
Sun, 29 Jul 2018 13:08:42 PDT
Sun, 29 Jul 2018 10:53:28 PDT
Sun, 29 Jul 2018 10:19:41 PDT
Sun, 29 Jul 2018 09:05:49 PDT
Sun, 29 Jul 2018 08:00:29 PDT
Sun, 29 Jul 2018 04:21:13 PDT
Sun, 29 Jul 2018 02:45:11 PDT
Sat, 28 Jul 2018 20:49:53 PDT
Sat, 28 Jul 2018 19:36:19 PDT
Sat, 28 Jul 2018 18:46:47 PDT
Sat, 28 Jul 2018 18:43:18 PDT
Sat, 28 Jul 2018 18:38:17 PDT
Sat, 28 Jul 2018 18:09:58 PDT
Sat, 28 Jul 2018 17:03:20 PDT
Sat, 28 Jul 2018 17:01:20 PDT
Sat, 28 Jul 2018 16:48:13 PDT
Sat, 28 Jul 2018 14:16:49 PDT
Sat, 28 Jul 2018 13:26:15 PDT
Sat, 28 Jul 2018 13:10:00 PDT
Sat, 28 Jul 2018 08:20:36 PDT
Sat, 28 Jul 2018 06:33:07 PDT
Fri, 27 Jul 2018 23:34:46 PDT
Fri, 27 Jul 2018 20:23:07 PDT
Fri, 27 Jul 2018 17:19:40 PDT
Fri, 27 Jul 2018 14:14:03 PDT
Fri, 27 Jul 2018 14:04:25 PDT
Fri, 27 Jul 2018 12:50:58 PDT
Fri, 27 Jul 2018 12:43:33 PDT
Fri, 27 Jul 2018 12:39:14 PDT
Fri, 27 Jul 2018 11:42:05 PDT
Fri, 27 Jul 2018 11:20:51 PDT
Fri, 27 Jul 2018 08:57:02 PDT
Fri, 27 Jul 2018 08:37:32 PDT
Fri, 27 Jul 2018 08:35:10 PDT
Fri, 27 Jul 2018 07:36:57 PDT
Fri, 27 Jul 2018 04:57:44 PDT
Fri, 27 Jul 2018 03:23:28 PDT
Thu, 26 Jul 2018 17:42:04 PDT
Thu, 26 Jul 2018 17:10:59 PDT
Thu, 26 Jul 2018 15:55:45 PDT
Thu, 26 Jul 2018 15:39:09 PDT
Thu, 26 Jul 2018 14:37:14 PDT
Thu, 26 Jul 2018 13:53:09 PDT
Thu, 26 Jul 2018 10:45:00 PDT
Thu, 26 Jul 2018 10:14:42 PDT
Thu, 26 Jul 2018 10:01:15 PDT
Thu, 26 Jul 2018 09:36:08 PDT
Thu, 26 Jul 2018 09:23:27 PDT
Thu, 26 Jul 2018 08:43:50 PDT
Thu, 26 Jul 2018 08:41:02 PDT
Thu, 26 Jul 2018 05:11:21 PDT
Thu, 26 Jul 2018 04:44:54 PDT
Thu, 26 Jul 2018 04:31:49 PDT
Thu, 26 Jul 2018 04:29:28 PDT
Thu, 26 Jul 2018 04:23:18 PDT
Thu, 26 Jul 2018 03:17:38 PDT
Thu, 26 Jul 2018 03:17:30 PDT
Thu, 26 Jul 2018 01:52:34 PDT
Thu, 26 Jul 2018 01:43:49 PDT
Wed, 25 Jul 2018 22:04:52 PDT
Wed, 25 Jul 2018 20:11:30 PDT
Wed, 25 Jul 2018 19:43:36 PDT
Wed, 25 Jul 2018 19:34:08 PDT
Wed, 25 Jul 2018 16:25:28 PDT
Wed, 25 Jul 2018 16:11:48 PDT
Wed, 25 Jul 2018 14:44:00 PDT
Wed, 25 Jul 2018 14:11:42 PDT
Wed, 25 Jul 2018 13:55:26 PDT
Wed, 25 Jul 2018 13:46:19 PDT
Wed, 25 Jul 2018 12:23:58 PDT
```

Comment: You have half-hour sized bins, and a lot of half-hours without any results. I think that's why the results "look weird". Try batching per day instead for such sparse data.

Comment: @CupcakeProtocol I believe the bin width is actually thirty seconds....

Comment: Thanks, @user8153. My gnuplot is obviously rusty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, your binning resolution is probably too high (gnuplot converts time data into seconds). You might also want to adjust the width of your boxes, and adjust your `timefmt` to match your data:

```
set xdata time
set timefmt "%d %b %Y %H:%M:S"
binwidth = 60 * 60   # 1 hour
bin(x,width) = width*floor(x/width)
set boxwidth binwidth
plot "data.txt" using (bin(timecolumn(2),binwidth)):(1.0) smooth frequency notitle with boxes
```

[image]